# Android:Cannot access android.os.AsyncTask.WorkRunnable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

```
private final WorkerRunnable<Params, Result> mWorker;

private static abstract class WorkerRunnable<Params, Result> implements Callable<Result> {
    Params[] mParams;
}
```

I take red line in `mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>()` row.This is java own class.I don't understand how can i take error.Please help me.

```
public AsyncTask(Looper callbackLooper) {
    mHandler = callbackLooper == null || callbackLooper == Looper.getMainLooper()
        ? getMainHandler()
        : new Handler(callbackLooper);

    mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            mTaskInvoked.set(true);
            Result result = null;
            try {
                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                //noinspection unchecked
                result = doInBackground(mParams);
                Binder.flushPendingCommands();
            } catch (Throwable tr) {
                mCancelled.set(true);
                throw tr;
            } finally {
                postResult(result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

I called execute in oncreate() method like this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_solution);

    resultt = findViewById(R.id.recognizeResult2);
    resultview = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    new WolframFeed().execute();

}
```

and I use AsyncTask like this

```
private class WolframFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private WAException exception;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result="";
        inputText = "solve " +resultt.getText().toString();
        try {

            Log.e("TRYing", "wolfram try/");

            WAEngine engine = new WAEngine();

            engine.setAppID(APP_ID);
            //engine.addPodState("Result__Step-by-step solution");
            engine.addFormat("plaintext");

            WAQuery query = engine.createQueryFromURL(createFullURL());
            /*WAQuery query = engine.createQuery();
            query.setInput(inputText);*/

            WAQueryResult queryResult = engine.performQuery(query);

            if (queryResult.isError()) {

                String err= "Query error" + "  error code: " + queryResult.getErrorCode() + "  error message: " + queryResult.getErrorMessage();
                Log.e("err: ",err);

            } else if (!queryResult.isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("err: " ,"Query was not understood; no results available.");

            } else {
                // Got a result.
                Log.e("err: ","Successful query. Pods follow:\n");

                for (WAPod pod : queryResult.getPods()) {
                    if (!pod.isError()) {
                        result+="\n";
                        for (WASubpod subpod : pod.getSubpods()) {
                            for (Object element : subpod.getContents()) {
                                if (element instanceof WAPlainText) {
                                    if(((WAPlainText) element).getText()!=""){
                                        result+=pod.getTitle();
                                        result+= ((WAPlainText) element).getText();
                                        result+="\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (WAException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        resultview.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Please help me where am i making a mistake.

Comment: Please post more code where you are creating the AsyncTask and calling execute()

Comment: I edit my question please help me. I need your helps. @Abhilash Bhaduri

Comment: Please hepl me how can i fix error i need your helps.

Comment: Try to convert WolframFeed to a public class in case it is not declared inside the same activity class